# Getting One Field Into An Array?

Tags: c#, linq

The following lines of code grabs a handful of rows from a database, and puts the value Table.Id into a list of integers.  I imagine there is a way to condense this code into a single line, but I'm not sure how.

```
var result db.Table.Where(a=>a.Value>0).ToList();
List<int> ids = new List<int>();
foreach(var row in result){
    ids.Add(row.Id);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Edit: My title says array, my example has a list, either one is fine.  Sorry if there was any confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var ids = db.Table.Where(a => a.Value > 0).Select(row => row.Id).ToList();
```

Should do the trick unless my fu is off

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var result = db.Table.Where(a=>a.Value>0)
                .Select(a=>a.Id)
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: How common is it to code in this style, where each extension method gets its own line and is indented?

Comment: I write in a similar style just to keep the filtering distinct, makes it easier on the eyes in the long run imo although I would space it differently, but that's just my style

Comment: Am not sure how Common it is..but it makes it more readable from my perspective...

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [List.ForEach Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx). So something like:

```
db.Table.Where(a=>a.Value>0).ToList().ForEach(delegate(Table row) { ids.Add(row.Id); });
```